# Can you sink Tall Ships?

Tags: moby-dick-the-video-game

So I'm playing [*Moby Dick: The Video Game*](http://www.kongregate.com/games/camaleonyco/moby-dick-the-video-game), and every now and then a tall ship comes by.  For anyone not familiar with that term, I'm talking about the large, masted ships.  (In this game, they are the ones that fire cannons at you.)  These ships usually kill me, and so far I've been unable to sink any of them, or even knock any sailors out of them.  Can they be destroyed at all?  If so, how many hits does it take?  Do I have to be a certain size before I can destroy them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that any ship can be sunk, but there are multiple ships with cannons and sails. I've sunken the first two, but it doesn't take a certain number of hits, I don't think. I think you just have to rock it until everybody falls off, then it breaks on it's own. I don't know if you have to be a certain size, but you can sink the first cannon one easily at 100 tons<strike>, and I think you have to be close to there for them to come.</strike>(Just had the second one come when I was really small, but it killed me before I could attack it.) Remember to use your boosts to jump up and fall on them.

EDIT: These are the two I'm talking about. That's as far as I've gotten so far, as that was one of Moby's last moments. :(
[image: Moby Dick - The Video Game screenshot showing the two ships that I'm talking about.]